# Angular 4, No provider for NgForm

Tags: angular

I have a bounch of components that are using ReactiveForms, but when i try to access them, i'm getting "No provider for NgForm".

The weird thing is this is not happening when running "ng serve" and it's just happening when running "ng serve --aot" or even when i deploy with "ng build --prod"

Anyone has an idea what it's going on here?

This is the full backtrace

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NgForm!
>   Error: No provider for NgForm!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9489)
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10577)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11080)
>       at *createProviderInstance (core.es5.js:10909)
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.*getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9489)
>       at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10577)
>       at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11080)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.es5.js:10909)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:766)
>       at zone.js:844
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
>       at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1427)

Comment: same here i had 4.0.0 and I was getting the issue, I upgraded to 4.2.6 but still aot build gives the same error.

Comment: @sij This was fixed one hour ago in 4.4.3

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/releases

Comment: How can i download 4.4.3 from npm, it says No compatible version found: @angular/http@4.4.3 for all angular modules

Comment: by using @latest I get 4.4.2

Comment: you can run npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save

Answer (score 1):

I'd double check that you're importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the correct module for the components that use the reactive form. I often run into this same type of problem with observable operators that are imported in one component, but not in another component that uses that operator. The app will run with `ng serve`, but not `ng build/aot`.

Comment: I have the ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module.ts. That is not the issue :/

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/releases